# Add a stylesheet created in pastebin.com

Tags: javascript, html, css, userscripts

I am creating a userscript for a friend of mine and it requires restyling the page a bit. For this I have made a stylesheet and it's now sitting at pastebin.com. I figured I could just add the stylesheet using the below line of code however it didn't work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<link href="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dHnQuGzj" rel="stylesheet" />';
```

I would rather use this method if possible as the final stylesheet would be rather long and I would like to keep the JavaScript to a minimum.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: and why not just add the same link to html?

Comment: @Hardy "I am creating a userscript..." there is your answer.

Comment: What is a *"userscript"*? - Google has several definitions for it... Also, regardless of what you specify as the language-type when you save a *paste*, the fact that the content at the *raw* URL is served with the mime-type `text/plain` should be enough of an indication that this is not the intended use of the feature.

Comment: @Emissary Added a tag for you.

Comment: okay but it should really be self-contained - you can manage style separate to logic to to keep things tidy but *"keeping javascript to a minimum"* isn't a good rationale for leeching bandwidth.  Chrome extensions allow you specify stylesheets in the manifest under `content_scripts` - I'm not familiar with it but I don't doubt *FF* does something similar too.  Why can't you bundle a css file in with your script?

Comment: hey, if you inspect the url " http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dHnQuGzj ", it is a html file with a pre tag containing the css code and it is NOT a css file. This is the reason why your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
var fileref = document.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```